# Reduce number of conditional operators

Tags: java

I have an String arraylist. Lets say

```
private final List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now I have to compare an incoming line against the items in the arraylist

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!(line.equals(fruits.get(0)) || line.contains(fruits.get(1)) ||
        line.contains(fruits.get(2)) || line.contains(fruits.get(3)) ||
        line.contains(fruits.get(4)) || line.contains(fruits.get(5)) ||
        line.contains(fruits.get(6)) || line.equals(fruits.get(7)    ||  line.equals(fruits.get(8)))) {
          //                   "DO SOMETHING"
     }
}
```

I have to match the string exactly for some cases and just use contains for some cases. But at last I should not have more than 3 conditions in my if clause.

Comment: Have you considered using a loop?

Comment: Build a regular expression.

Comment: Write a method using if statements, but no conditional operators.

Comment: It is possible to check if a String is a subset of any String in an array, using [`StringUtils.containsAny(CharSequence, CharSequence...)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-). The real problem is that some are to be checked for equality only. The only option would be to loop through the function and knowing which elements having to be equal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've got a compilation error here: `line.equals(fruits.get(7) || line.equals(fruits.get(8)))`.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the list of fruits? E.g. to turn it into a map of fruits with the comparison method (equals or contains) as their value using an enum. Then you can loop over the entry set of the map and use each value to determine whether to use equals() or contains() on the key.

Comment: is it intentional to have 0 to 6 using `contains` and 7 to 8 using `equals` ? and, is it intentional that you only want to check first 9 elements, even the list contains more than 9?

Comment: yes , the list can be expanded but the initial 9 elements will be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use either equals() or contains() on each fruit in the list and your fruits are ever growing, consider turning your list into a map, where you store the desired method by fruit.

```
private enum Method {
    CONTAINS,
    EQUALS;
}

@Test
public void testFruits() throws IOException {
    Map<String, Method> methodByFruit = new HashMap<>();
    methodByFruit.put("apple", Method.CONTAINS);
    methodByFruit.put("pear", Method.CONTAINS);
    methodByFruit.put("grenade apple", Method.CONTAINS);
    methodByFruit.put("banana", Method.EQUALS);
    methodByFruit.put("kiwi", Method.EQUALS);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("kiwi2"));

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        boolean success = false;
        for (Entry<String, Method> entry : methodByFruit.entrySet()) {
            String fruit = entry.getKey();
            Method method = entry.getValue();
            if (method == Method.EQUALS) {
                success = line.equals(fruit);
            } else {
                success = line.contains(fruit);
            }
            if (success) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!success) {
            System.out.println("DO SOMETHING");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is not clear. Whether the equality check is specifically for index `7` or `8` only or what. But anyway here is my suggestion. you can make a simple method to check if `line` contains subset from the `list`

```
public boolean isFound(List<String> f, String l){
    for(int i=0;i<f.size();i++){
        if(l.contains(f.get(i)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can check it like this:

```
if(isFound(fruits, line) || fruits.contains(line)){
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: equals is used only for index 0,7,8